# How to read UPF pseudopotential for ultrasoft pseudopotential simple in a fortran program

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, electronic-structure, condensed-matter, pseudopotentials

I'm currently working on calculating semiempirical local and nonlocal matrix elements for Ga. To proceed with my calculations, I need to extract specific parameters  from the UPF (Unified Pseudopotential Format) file for Ga. I've encountered challenges in this process. I haven't found a solution yet. If anyone has insights or suggestions on how to efficiently read and extract the required parameters from a UPF pseudopotential file for Ga on FORTRAN, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For now, the UPF standard is defined [on `Quantum ESPRESSO`'s website](https://pseudopotentials.quantum-espresso.org/home/unified-pseudopotential-format). Looks like the documentation is for an XML-like format, but it will be (or has already been, that documentation is pretty old) converted to true XML later. If you really want to read the file as-is, that may be enough. An actual XML reader like [FoXy](https://github.com/Fortran-FOSS-Programmers/FoXy) (if your Fortran is >= 2008) might help.

Failing that, `Quantum ESPRESSO` deals with pseudopotential files with the `upflib` directory, [which you can read here](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/tree/develop/upflib). In particular, the files [`write_upf_new.f90`](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/develop/upflib/write_upf_new.f90?ref_type=heads) and [`read_upf_new.f90`](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/develop/upflib/read_upf_new.f90?ref_type=heads) look like they will more or less explain what you need! (They should read either the XML or the older 2.1 format of `upf` files, too.)

Comment: Hi elutionary, I'm still grappling with reading certain parameters like qfunc(mesh, composite_index) in Fortran 90, especially when composite_index = nb*(nb+1)/2. I'm trying to extract information like first_index, second_index, composite_index, and angular_momentum from a tag file. If the angular momentum values differ for the same composite number, I'm struggling to read both tag items. I've gone through around 80% of the Fortran 90 code but need further assistance. Any additional ideas would be greatly appreciated. I've shared my challenge with the community for input.